# jquery validation and function

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to add my function to jquery validation. Without linking to any html elements, just call function when "validate" event occurs. I just try by the following way:

```
$('#form1').validate({
    rules: {
        hours: true
}
});


$.validator.addMethod("hours", function (value, element, param) {
    return false;
});
```

it does not work. How to do it correctly?

**ADDED**

Html:

```
<form action="/Home/Valid8" id="form1" method="post" name="form1"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="7xLtyNBlPK1kZ3YD5BQwtbxNq2kQEq1M-t1zq3ZCUs8gnUjStQNJ14QEybjo_tbU_x2QD0KfT79YoJg4CqhuaIir73fVJSf2V8CI4crUxJI1" />    <div class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Number">Number</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Number must be a number." data-val-range="The field Number must be between 0 and 24." data-val-range-max="24" data-val-range-min="0" data-val-required="The Number field is required." id="Number" name="Number" type="number" value="0" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Number" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div>
            <div class="form-control-static input-validation-error"
                 data-val="true"
                 data-val-number="The field Number must be a number."
                 data-val-hours="The field Number must be between 0 and 24."
                 data-val-hours-max="24"
                 data-val-required="The Number field is required."
                 id="Number2" name="Number2" />
            <br />
            <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Number2" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <input type="button" id="btnSet" value="set" />

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Script:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#btnSet').on('click', function () {
            $('#Number2').html('-5');
        });
    });

    $('#form1').validate({
        rules: {
            Number2: {
                hours: true
            }
        }
    });


    $.validator.addMethod("hours", function (value, element, param) {
        //var r = (value > 0)
        var r = false;

        return r;
    }, 'Error Message Here');

    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal("hours", "max");
</script>
```

btnSet just is used for emulate actions of user.
When I click  "Submit" page is reloading (even a validator of first field does not work). If I remove

```
    $('#form1').validate({
        rules: {
            Number2: {
                hours: true
            }
        }
    });
```

then validator of first field works

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:jquery-validation-engine] tag for the jQuery Validate plugin... it's not the same thing.  You also need to show the relevant HTML and explain what you're really trying to do here.

Comment: what do you mean under "do not use the jquery-validation-engine tag"?

Comment: You had originally tagged the question with the wrong plugin.

Answer (score 1):

**How to Use `.addMethod()`**:

You failed to assign the rule to an input field.  Without seeing your HTML, I have no idea about the field or its actual `name`.

```
$('#form1').validate({
    rules: {
        yourField: { // <-- the field NAME attribute
            hours: true
        }
    }
});
```

You also need to define an error message...

```
$.validator.addMethod("hours", function (value, element, param) {
    return false;
}, 'Error Message Here');
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/efqoLwr7/**

---

> "I want to add my function to jquery validation.  Without linking to any html elements, just call function when "validate" event occurs."

You have to explain exactly what you want to do.  You can only assign rules/methods to input fields; you can't just run any method at any time.

- The `.addMethod()` method is only used for creating new/custom rules that are assigned to one or more input fields.
- There is no such thing as a "validate" event.  The jQuery Validate plugin fires the declared rules/methods on the assigned input field(s) when the `focusout`, `keyup`, or button `click` events occur on the relevant elements within your `form`.

Otherwise, there are various options you can override with your own functions that will allow you to customize certain behaviors.  [Refer to the documentation for the complete list of options](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/).

Comment: strange, but does not work. Added details to the answer

Comment: @OlegSh, your `Number2` element is a `div`.  You **cannot** validate a `div`.  You can only validate an `input`, `select` or `textarea` element using this plugin.

Comment: changed to input type="text", it works, but other validation does not work. I want to extend validation, not replace. Also, with input type="hidden" it does not work too. For me the best variant is to add one more function for validation (to existing validator). Just call one more function. Is it possible?

Comment: @OlegSh, I reviewed your edits.  You **cannot** call the `.validate()` method if you're also using `unobtrusive-validation`.  The unobtrusive validation plugin should be removed if you want to customize jQuery Validate.  And with that, your edited question is absolutely nothing like the original posted  version.

Comment: why nothing like the original posted version? I just want to call one more function when page is validating. Is it possible?

Comment: @OlegSh, because you failed to mention `unobtrusive-validation`.  If you're using `unobtrusive-validation`, then you **cannot** call the `.validate()` method.  The `.validate()` method can only be called **once** to initialize the plugin and all subsequent calls are ignored.  Since it's **already** called by `unobtrusive`, then your instance is ignored.

Comment: @OlegSh,  You also cannot call a function when the "page is validating", because "validating" is not an event.  The jQuery Validate plugin fires the declared rules/methods on the assigned input field(s) when the `focusout`, `keyup`, or button `click` events occur on the relevant elements within your `form`.